# Redis activedefrag performance reduction?

Tags: redis

Currently running into an issue with one of my redis boxes where the AOF write is causing a spike in Memory from 70% up to 86% and then back down. While I am not sure how to reduce this rewrite size. One thing I noticed looking at the info is that I don't have activedefrag enabled and definitely think I should.

Current memory output:

```
Redis 5.0.4
# Memory
used_memory:21078484704
used_memory_human:19.63G
used_memory_rss:44272873472
used_memory_rss_human:41.23G
used_memory_peak:34592086488
used_memory_peak_human:32.22G
used_memory_peak_perc:60.93%
used_memory_overhead:60934294
used_memory_startup:791144
used_memory_dataset:21017550410
used_memory_dataset_perc:99.71%
allocator_allocated:21078817576
allocator_active:21134442496
allocator_resident:21881040896
total_system_memory:66721947648
total_system_memory_human:62.14G
used_memory_lua:40960
used_memory_lua_human:40.00K
used_memory_scripts:448
used_memory_scripts_human:448B
number_of_cached_scripts:2
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.00
allocator_frag_bytes:55624920
allocator_rss_ratio:1.04
allocator_rss_bytes:746598400
rss_overhead_ratio:2.02
rss_overhead_bytes:22391832576
mem_fragmentation_ratio:2.10
mem_fragmentation_bytes:23194465048
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:1048576
mem_clients_slaves:66616
mem_clients_normal:12172422
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

I'm fairly certain enabling activedefrag will help me out quite a bit, but I am not sure what kind of performance hit running this would cause. Would this be safe to run/enable or do I need to reboot the server first to clear the memory (definitely not preferable).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If you use the jemalloc allocator, the overhead of `activedefrag yes` can typically be ignored.

(On Linux and on AWS ElastiCache, jemalloc is the default. In your configuration, it is also the case:
`mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0`)

---

Of course, rebooting the server is one option to deal with fragmentation but often it is not possible. That is is why activedefrag is a better option for most workloads.

Should you be concerned about the overhead? No, you do not have to worry. Except for specific edge cases, you will not notify any impact by enabling active defragmentation. Also note that some optimizations will depend on the jemalloc allocator. If you are using another allocator, however, you have to be more careful and measuring the effects would be prudent.

Edges cases could include workloads that are not long running and were ignoring fragmentation might result in a minor performance boost. For long running workloads, which are more typical, the performance degradation of fragmentation should be more of a concern then the minor overhead of active defragmentation.

In older Redis versions (Redis 4), the implementation was less optimized. Since then it has been improved (Redis 5 or higher). Now the overhead can be ignored in most situation. My recommendation is to enable it by default, unless you have measured that disabling it improves your throughput. In the production systems that I worked with, I did not notice any negative effects on performance after enabling `activedefrag yes`.

Similar question of that option on serverfault:

- [Are there situations were activedefrag should be kept disabled in Redis 5 (with Jemalloc allocator)](https://serverfault.com/q/971804/151221)